# Sharepoint managed client object model - Updating Eventdate in calender

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

I am using managed client object model in sharepoint and I am adding EventDate and on adding that I am catching exception which says Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldValueException

```
if (thisfield.StaticName.ToLower() == "eventdate" 
 || thisfield.StaticName.ToLower() == "enddate")
  newitem.ParseAndSetFieldValue(thisfield.InternalName, spitem[thisfield.StaticName].ToString());
```

Please let me know what should I do .

Thanks

Comment: Here is the line                                                 
`code`
if (thisfield.StaticName.ToLower() == "eventdate" || thisfield.StaticName.ToLower() == "enddate")

                                                    newitem.ParseAndSetFieldValue(thisfield.InternalName, spitem[thisfield.StaticName].ToString());

Answer (score 1):

Please Follow with this Code

```
 ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://yoursite");
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
ctx.Load(items); // loading all the fields
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach(var item in items)
{
    // important thing is, that here you must have the right type
    // i.e. item["Modified"] is DateTime
    item["fieldName"] = newValue;

    // do whatever changes you want

    item.Update(); // important, rembeber changes
}
ctx.ExecuteQuery(); // important, commit changes to the server
```